# Construction of the set of positive integers via set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets such that
$$|A|+|B| = |A \cup C|$$
with $C \sim B$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$.
Show that for any choices of $A$ and $B$, we can always found such $C$.
Also, explain its relation to the axiom of natural number.

**Here, natural number is the set of all positive integers.**

${}$

**Attempt:**

Let $A$ and $B$ be any finite sets.
If $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then we can pick $C=B$ such that $C \sim B, A \cap C = \emptyset$, and $|A| + |B| = |A \cup C|$.

Now, let's analyze the case when $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$.

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots, a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_m\}$ where $a_i < a_{i+1}, b_i < b_{i+1},$ and $a_i=b_j$ for some $i$ and $j$; WLOG, let $a_n=b_m$.
Hence, $A \cap B = \{a_n\} = \{b_m\} \ne \emptyset$ and $\max\{A \cup B\} = a_n=b_m$.

Now, we can construct $C=\{b_{m+1},b_{m+2},\ldots,b_{2m}\}$ where $a_i,b_j<b_k$ for all $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n;j=1,2,3,\ldots,m$, and $k=m+1,m+2,\ldots,2m$. Then, we got $|C|=|B|=m, A \cap C = \emptyset, A \cup C = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n,b_{m+1},b_{m+2},\ldots,b_{2m}\}$ so that
$|A \cup C|=n+m=|A|+|B|$.

${}$

Now, for the relation to axiom of natural number, I was thinking about the definition of the $+$ operation as follows:
$$n+1 := n \cup \{n\}$$
for all $n \in \Bbb N$. But, I didn't know to connect this.
Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your proof doesn't work. $C' = (B - A) \cup (A \cap B)$ is actually $B$ itself and so $C \subseteq B$. There is no guarantee $C$ won't include an element in $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @0XLR So, how to handle it?

Comment: $A \cup B \subset \mathbb Z_+$ is finite so it has a maximum $n$. So you can construct $C$ of the same size as $B$ but from numbers greater than $n$. So it is guaranteed to not intersect $A$.

Comment: @0XLR See my edit. Does it true?